# PHP configure error DBA: Could not find necessary header file(s)

Tags: php, linux, unix, centos

hello i have a Centos 7 machine.

i decided to install from source the apache,mysql,php.

i already install from source apache & mysql packages (requirements: with apr(source),apr-util(source),pcre-devel(yum installed),perl(yum installed)). now, i trying to install php and the configuration file stops at extensions section of install and says:

```
configure: error: DBA: Could not find necessary header file(s)
```

1) what should i do to repair it?

i saw on internet that i can fix it with db4-devel, the problem is that theres no db4-devel in CentOS 7.

2) theres any replacement package for this?

and one more question:

3) how can i make php(7.0.3) install all extensions in ./configure?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
apt-get install libdb-dev
```

As for extensions (if you have a reference installation): Execute `php-config` and use the configure-options from there.

Otherwise you have to think of which extensions you want and add them to the configure-script.